# ESLint & Emmet Key Binding Conflict

Tags: sublimetext3, reactjs, eslint, emmet

Since I started using ESLint the Ctrl + E keybinding no longer works for Emmet inside JSX. Ctrl E is running ESLint instead of expanding abbreviations in Emmet.

I'm using Sublime Text 3.

I'm unclear on how to edit my key bindings user settings file to have Emmet override ESLint. I've searched for over 30 minutes and can't find anybody else with this problem

What is the correct process?

I tried to edit the keybindings settings file to make Emmet expand on ctrl+shift+e but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
    { "keys": ["super+shift+v"], "command": "paste" },
    { "keys": ["super+r"],  "command": "reindent" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+e"], "command": "Emmet: Expand Abbreviation" }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I didn't realize you can edit keybindings specifically on each plugin.  I went to Preferences > Package Settings > Eslint > Keybindings > Default and just changed the ESlint keybiding to ctrl + l instead and Emmet works in JSX again.